# How to remove object which contain specific characters from global environment in RStudio?

Tags: r, list, environment-variables

Based on some quick searches online I have found that you can clear your global environment using:

```r
rm(list = ls()) 
# where ls() is a list of objects in your environment
```

I have also come across variations of code which remove all except some specified objects:

```r
rm(list=ls()[! ls() %in% c("object1","object2")])
rm(list=(ls()[ls()!="object1"])
```

***My question:***

Let's say I have these objects in my environment: df1, df2, df3, df4, final_dataset

Is it possible for me to remove all the datasets which begin with (or contain) "df"?

I know you can simply type:

```r
rm(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

But if I had many many objects which contained "df" it would be inefficient to enter them all manually - especially if I have loads of temporary variables I'd like to remove. Hence, is there a better way to do this?

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: Or `rm(list = ls(pattern = "^df[:1-4:]"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the `pattern` argument

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$'))
```

Or if there are many objects of the same pattern and want to remove only 'df1' to 'df4', use `paste`

```
rm(list = paste0('df', 1:4))
```